# Using HingeEmbeddingLoss in PyTorch for Binary Classification

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am working on a text classification problem using Hugging Face's XLM-RoBERTa model in PyTorch. I want to use the nn.HingeEmbeddingLoss for my custom loss function since it seems suitable for my binary classification task.

According to the PyTorch documentation, nn.HingeEmbeddingLoss expects labels to be either 1 or -1. However, my original dataset has labels as 0 and 1. Accordingly, I converted my labels from (0, 1) to (1, -1).

On running the CustomTrainer with the loss function set to HingeEmbeddingLoss, and calling trainer.train() i get the following error:

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

I have been given the understand that this happens because the labels are expected to be in the range [0,number of classes-1] .

Can someone please guide me on how to proceed?

Here is my code:

```
class CustomTrainer(Trainer):
     def compute_loss(self,model,inputs,return_outputs = False):
        outputs = model(**inputs)
        logits = outputs.get("logits")
        labels = inputs.get("labels")
        #print(logits)
        #print(labels)
        print("Logits size:", logits.size())  # or logits.shape
        print("Labels size:", labels.size())
        labels =nn.functional.one_hot(labels, num_classes=2).float()
        #labels = labels.squeeze(dim=-1) ##new
        loss_func = nn.HingeEmbeddingLoss()
        #(weight=class_weights)
        loss = loss_func(logits,labels)
        return (loss,outputs) if return_outputs else loss
```

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hinge_embedding_loss.py", line 190, in <module>
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(path,local_files_only=True)
  File "/Data/home/ug22/2203321/text_cls/seq_cls_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/tokenization_auto.py", line 752, in from_pretrained
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
  File "/Data/home/ug22/2203321/text_cls/seq_cls_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 1082, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, unused_kwargs = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Data/home/ug22/2203321/text_cls/seq_cls_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 644, in get_config_dict
    config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/Data/home/ug22/2203321/text_cls/seq_cls_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 699, in _get_config_dict
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/Data/home/ug22/2203321/text_cls/seq_cls_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 360, in cached_file
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: Hinge_Embedding/bloom-560m 4e-5 does not appear to have a file named config.json. Checkout 'https://huggingface.co/Hinge_Embedding/bloom-560m 4e-5/None' for available files.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [1,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [2,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [3,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [4,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [7,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
```

Here is the full error, for the model bigscience/bloom-560m

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error?